# Is Data locality concept applicable for Reducers also?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My understanding :

The concept of Data locality applies only for Mapper only as it deals with input files.

Is Reducers also will use Data locality concept while processing?

**Data locality:**

Data locality refers to processing of the data where it resides by bringing the computation to the data, rather than requesting data from its location.

1. While computing the data, Mappers and Reducers 'll work.
2. Mappers use Data locality while computing the data.
3. Reducers take input as Mappers output.

Assuming that Mappers output (intermediate data) stored in different data nodes.

Are Reducers use Data locality while computing?

Comment: can you elaborate a little more about your question

Answer (score 0):

No, Data-Locality concept applies to MAPPERS only.

Reducers are assigned based on partitoner logic (on unique keys of MAP outputs)